# install paraller printer

Tags: drivers, 12.10, printing

i have an hp printer Deskjet 710c. I have tried to connect him to ubuntu 12.10 but when I click add in printers it gives me a host. Does it mean the driver? If so where can I get the driver for my printer?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what "click add in printers" means, but I've always had luck with installing printers by pointing my browser at `http://localhost:631` and using the CUPS interface to add the printer, select the printer model, etc. "Drivers" as such, have not been a problem.

Just in case it helps, whenever something asks you for a hostname for a locally connected device, "`localhost`" is a good answer, or the IP address `127.0.0.1`. They both mean "this node, right here, the one you're running on".

Comment: By "click add printers" he means he has gone into system settings then selected "printers" then and pressed the green symbol for add a printer. I know it is there 'cos I'm trying to install an hp720 on Ubuntu 12.04. Extremely frustrating 'cos I keep seeing questions by folk who are having problems with the 720c but have clearly got the system to recognize it! (lucky them!)
I'm still sending docs to email then out to windows and printing from the dreaded (but functional OS. (not ideal)